# How to overcome Jarsigner reporting " Signature algorithm: MD5withRSA (weak)"

Tags: android, delphi, keytool

I have a delphi 10.3.3 android app which is signed with a custom keystore.
This is generated by a keytool command which reads in part:

```
  KeyTool -genkeypair ... -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA256withRSA  -keysize 2048  -v
```

When I view the resulting APK with "jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs myapkname", it reports:

```
    Digest algorithm: SHA-256
    Signature algorithm: MD5withRSA (weak), 2048-bit key

WARNING: The jar will be treated as unsigned, because it is signed with a weak algorithm that is now disabled by the security property:
```

How do I get rid of the "MD5withRSA" and get a non-deprecated signature algorithm?

(I have tried the suggested migration to "Non JKS/JCEKS" keystore type. It makes no difference.
I have also tried a key algorithm of DSA with a few variations on sigalg but they seem to be problematic. I have also tried generating it with the wizard but it produces the same result.)

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing value of SHA256withRSA to both `-keyalg` and `-sigalg` parameters?

Comment: @SilverWarrior I don't believe the syntax allows that. key algorithm should be one of RSA or DSA  (or possibly EC).